# How to know if two lines intersect using r? is there an equation to check easily without looking at graph?

Tags: r

This code gets the data needed to make two different lines. I was wondering if there was a way to see if two lines intersected easily.

```
# generate data
red <- matrix(runif(n = 4, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 2)# gets the 4 points for the first line
blue <- matrix(runif(n = 4, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 2)# gets the 4 points for second line

# make a plot
plot(red, col = "red", pch = 16, cex = 2,
     asp = 1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "", ylab = "")##plots both points red

abline(v = c(0,1), col = "grey", lty = 2)
abline(h = c(0,1), col = "grey", lty = 2)

segments(red[1,1], red[1,2], red[2,1], red[2,2], lwd = 2, col = "red")#Makes the line segment
points(blue, col = "blue", pch = 16, cex = 2,
     asp = 1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))# does same thing for blue line
segments(blue[1,1], blue[1,2], blue[2,1], blue[2,2], lwd = 2, col = "blue") 
##makes all of the plots and can see if the plot intersects.`
```

[image: what The intersected lines look like]

Comment: The red line is the same as the code as the blue at the top of the code forgot to add that in there.

Comment: Get their slopes and intercepts and check where they cross and if that is within the viewable area (ie for x in [0, 1])

Comment: Two lines with unequal slopes will always intersect somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a practical answer using simple algebra wrapped up in a function.

The process is to find the slope and y intercept of both lines, and solve simultaneous equations to find the intersection. If both line segments have the same gradient the answer is undefined so return `NA`.

Return the x, y co-ordinates of the intersection if it is within the x range of one of the line segments, otherwise return NA

```r
check_intersect <- function(mat1, mat2)
{
  dy1 <- mat1[,2][which.max(mat1[,1])] - mat1[,2][which.min(mat1[,1])]
  dy2 <- mat2[,2][which.max(mat2[,1])] - mat2[,2][which.min(mat2[,1])]
  dx1 <- max(mat1[,1]) - min(mat1[,1])
  dx2 <- max(mat2[,1]) - min(mat2[,1])
  m1  <- dy1/dx1
  m2  <- dy2/dx2
  if(m1 == m2) return(NA)
  c1  <- mat1[1, 2] - m1 * mat1[1, 1]
  c2  <- mat2[1, 2] - m2 * mat2[1, 1]
  x   <- (c2 - c1)/(m1 - m2)
  y   <- m1 * x + c1
  if(x > min(mat1[,1]) & x < max(mat1[,1])) 
    return(c(x, y)) 
  else 
    return(NA)
}
```

Now test this with a reprex:

```r
set.seed(123)

red <- matrix(runif(n = 4, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 2)# gets the 4 points for the first line
blue <- matrix(runif(n = 4, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 2)# gets the 4 points for second line

# make a plot
plot(red, col = "red", pch = 16, cex = 2,
     asp = 1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "", ylab = "")##plots both points red

abline(v = c(0,1), col = "grey", lty = 2)
abline(h = c(0,1), col = "grey", lty = 2)

segments(red[1,1], red[1,2], red[2,1], red[2,2], lwd = 2, col = "red")#Makes the line segment
points(blue, col = "blue", pch = 16, cex = 2,
     asp = 1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))# does same thing for blue line
segments(blue[1,1], blue[1,2], blue[2,1], blue[2,2], lwd = 2, col = "blue") 

p <- check_intersect(red, blue)
points(p[1], p[2], cex = 2)
```

[image]

```r
p
#> [1] 0.5719010 0.6781469
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>